# Unable to click input after checking for form changes

Tags: javascript, html, input, click, onbeforeunload

This is my first post here so please, be gentle.

I am attempting to perform an autosave on a form when the user navigates away from the page that they're on.  Mainly, it's for when a user has been working with a record, then goes on to navigate to a new record without first saving their work.  So far, I've been able to successfully detect if the form contents have been changed, but I'm hung up on how to perform the save.

Here's the code that I thought would work:

```
var $formContents = $(document.getElementById("allData"));
origForm = $formContents.serialize();

window.onunload = function() {
   var $formContents = $(document.getElementById("allData"));
   nowForm = $formContents.serialize();

   if (nowForm !== origForm) {
      console.log('Changes detected.');
      document.getElementById('saveBut').click();
   }
   else {
      console.log('No changes detected');
   }
}
```

Now, the data comparison is working.  If I've changed anything in the form, I get the "Changes detected" note in the console.  If I haven't, I get the "No changes detected."

However, the "document.getElementById('saveBut').click();" is not running, and the console shows no errors.  The 'saveBut' input is contained in a post-method form, and it triggers php code to save the form data to my SQL server.

FWIW, here's the html on the input:

```
<form method="post" id="save">
   <input type="submit" form="allData" value="Save Changes" id="saveBut" name="saveBut"/>
</form>

<form method="post" id="allData">
   <input type="hidden" name="formData[]" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
   <div class="info">
      Sermon Date: <input type="date" name="formData[]" value="<?php echo $row['sermon_date']; ?>">
      Sermon Location: <input type="text" name="formData[]" value="<?php echo $row['sermon_location']; ?>">
      Call to Worship: <input type="text" name="formData[]" value="<?php echo $row['call_to_worship']; ?>">
      Hymn of Response: <input type= "text" name="formData[]" value="<?php echo $row['hymn_of_response']; ?>">
   </div>

   <br><hr style="width:90%"><br>

   <div class="top">
      Pericope:
      <input type="text" size="40" name="formData[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['pericope'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>">
//and on and on...
</form>
```

I have also tried calling the php code directly by replacing

```
document.getElementById('saveBut').click();
```

with:

```
$.get('saverec.php', function(data) {
   eval(data);
});
```

And then I tried:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "saverec.php"
});
```

But neither worked, and I still wound up with the same result being "Changes detected" in my console log, but no errors.  I'm sure I'm missing something really basic, but I can't figure out what that might be.

Is there a way to make my saverec.php code run in this manner, or do I need to abandon this mess and come up with a different way?

---

Edit:

I'm adding the code from my saverec.php file.  FYI, there aren't any problems with this code as it runs fine when the user clicks on the 'saveBut' input.

```
<?php

$location = "i.p.add.ress";
$username = "my_username";
$password = "my_password";
$dbname = "my_database_name";
$tableName = "my_table_name";
$conn = new mysqli($location, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$allData = $_POST['formData'];
$currentID = $allData[0];

//write the form data to the new record
class updateRecord {
    public function __construct ($colName, $data, $currentID) {
        $this->colName = $colName;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->currentID = $currentID;
    }

    public function writeDataText() {
        global $conn;
        $ID = strval($this->currentID);
        $tableName = "sermon_prep_database";
        $sql = "UPDATE " . $tableName . " SET " . $this->colName . "='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $this->data) . "' WHERE ID=" . $this->currentID;
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}

//write all the data to the proper columns
$row = new updateRecord('sermon_date', $allData[1], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('sermon_location', $allData[2], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('call_to_worship', $allData[3], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('hymn_of_response', $allData[4], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('pericope', $allData[5], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('pericope_texts', $allData[6], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('sermon_text', $allData[7], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('fcft', $allData[8], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('gat', $allData[9], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('cpt', $allData[10], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('purpose_bridge', $allData[11], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('fcfs', $allData[12], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('gas', $allData[13], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('cps', $allData[14], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('sermon_title', $allData[15], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('sermon_scripture', $allData[16], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('text_outline', $allData[17], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('research_notes', $allData[18], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('sermon_outline', $allData[19], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('illustrations', $allData[20], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();
$row = new updateRecord('sermon_manuscript', $allData[21], $currentID);
$row->writeDataText();

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert ('Changes saved to ID ' + $currentID);
</script>";
```

Comment: Where is the actual php code for the saving action?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't let me paste the code in here.  It's too long.  But the saving code is working fine, and runs properly when the input is clicked by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax call should work, have you tried:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "saverec.php",
   success: function(data){
      console.log('Changes saved.');
   }
 });
```

And you should have only one form to get the data:

```
<form method="post" id="save">
   <input type="hidden" name="formData[]" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
   <div class="info">
      Sermon Date: <input type="date" name="formData[]" value="<?php echo $row['sermon_date']; ?>">
      Sermon Location: <input type="text" name="formData[]" value="<?php echo $row['sermon_location']; ?>">
      Call to Worship: <input type="text" name="formData[]" value="<?php echo $row['call_to_worship']; ?>">
      Hymn of Response: <input type= "text" name="formData[]" value="<?php echo $row['hymn_of_response']; ?>">
   </div>

   <br><hr style="width:90%"><br>

   <div class="top">
      Pericope:
      <input type="text" size="40" name="formData[]" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['pericope'], ENT_QUOTES); ?>">
//and on and on...
   <input type="submit" form="allData" value="Save Changes" id="saveBut" name="saveBut"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey, we're getting closer!  On success, console definitely showed "Changes saved."  However, nothing was written to SQL, so I'll bet it's simply a matter that the formData array hadn't been transfered to $_POST.  There must be a way to get the formData[] info into $_POST without the input having been clicked.  I'll search for that, but you might beat me to it.

Comment: Edited the answer, you need one form

Comment: Bingo!  I marked this as accepted because it got me almost all the way there.  What I found out was that I needed to add data:nowform after url:"saverec.php" in ajax so that the current form data made it into the $_POST of the php code.  Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this, I figured I'd add the code that finally let me do an autosave of the form at onbeforeunload:

```
//get the initial state of the form and store it into a variable
var $formContents = $(document.getElementById("allData"));
origForm = $formContents.serialize();

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   //get the current state of the form on BeforeUnload and store it into a variable             
   var $formContents = $(document.getElementById("allData"));
   nowForm = $formContents.serialize();
   //compare the current state of the form with the initial state of the form             
   if (nowForm !== origForm) {
      console.log('Changes detected.');
      //use ajax to post the current form data to saverec.php
      $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: 'saverec.php',
         data: nowForm,
         success: function(data){
            console.log('Changes saved.');
         }
      });
   }
   else {
      console.log('No changes detected');
   }
}
```

Of course, this means that the form will be saved even if the user doesn't want it to be, but that can be easily remedied with some sort of cancel button that overrides this onbeforeunload code.  Besides, it's really not an issue with this application.